# How to check if a LaTeX package has been installed?

Tags: latex, package-management

How to check if a LaTeX package has been installed in Ubuntu?

When installing, I followed the methods mentioned in [math.arizona.edu](http://math.arizona.edu/support/tex/accountpackages.html) and [n.wikibooks.org](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you know the name of the `.sty` or `.cls` file from the package, you can do

```
kpsewhich <filename>
```

and it show you the location of the file where Latex system finds the file.  If `kpsewhich` doesn't find it, you probably didn't install the files correctly or didn't run `mktexlsr` or `texhash`.

Also, please show us the output of

```
echo $TEXINPUTS
```

from the commandline.

Comment: kpsewchih and echo $TEXTINPUTS produce no output - what might be the cause? I'm on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: You might not have the package installed - which package are you trying to install?